Can Google Play approve an app that crashes immediately on launch?
I recently submitted my app to the Google Play Store, and it was approved without any issues. However, after release, I found that the app crashes immediately when installed and opened.
This has left me wondering: does Google Play conduct any automated or manual checks for crashes during their review process? If the app crashes on launch, how is it possible for it to still be approved?
For context, the app was working fine during development and testing, so I'm not sure how this crash slipped through. Any insights into the Google Play review process for crash detection would be helpful!

Must've passed some of the tests, it may not be triggered as a "startup crash" if it happens later in the app's lifecycle, but it definitely won't last for long on the Store if it crashes on startup on the newer versions of Android.

What do you mean it won't last long? It will be unpublished from the store?

Yes, if it's not working at all, it will be taken down. (eventually)

I uploaded a new working build, but the review process is taking very long.

Yeah, tell me about it...

There are 3 scenarios:

If it crashes on all versions of Android, it will definitely be
rejected
If it crashes on some versions but works on others, it will very likely also be rejected
If it crashes on only one, older version, only this might pass, (but it’s still not guaranteed)

The app must pass pre-launch tests, and a crash will unfortunately almost always lead to rejection.
(because it would decrease the Store's quality and reputation)
It also depends where the crash happens in the app's lifecycle, since it passed the test for publishing, the crash might not be picked  as a "startup crash" by the tests, and that explains why it passed. (but if its unstable, it won't last for long on the Store)
You should definitely always test, and address all crashes on as many versions of Android as possible to avoid rejection or removal of the app later from the Store. 

That's what I thought also. It should be the bare minimum requirement that the app launches correctly. Not sure how the approve was given in these circumstances.

The crash occurs on all versions, so it should have definitely been rejected, but it didn't and the app was released on store and the users can't access it now.

The crash is probably not picked by some tests, because it happens later in the app's lifecycle, so it's not considered as a "startup crash",  I think that's why it got published. (but i won't last for long if its unstable)

No, Google Play typically does not approve apps that crash immediately upon launch. To ensure a positive user experience, apps submitted to the Google Play Store must meet certain quality standards and guidelines.
